# Maven: Conditional Execution upon IT Success / Failure

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson, integration-testing, jenkins

Here is something I''ve tried to come up with an idea, but I'm not sure.

We do have a module which should be built, deployed and then integration test begins (via failsafe, but others might be fine). We'd like to selectvely invoke mojos based on its results.

I think verify from failsafe should do the trick (with probably some gmaven trickery), but how to validate the results of failsafe? Perhaps some Test Listener Magic with JUnit could help?

Any ideas how could we achieve that, considering a Maven (and Probably Hudson) scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let do the first part of that do Hudson (run integration tests) and do a failsafe:check in your integration test cycle and based on the result you can start a dependenant job in Hudson to run an other job whatever this job will do. But you can't execute selective mojos based on results (afak).